# how to insert custom logic in ng="$last"

Tags: angularjs

As you can see below, I use an ng-repeat to iterate through a series of products, and, at the end, use a custom directive like this

```
<div ng="$last" some-product-directive datajson=product></div>
```

The problem is that I want to be able to choose from several different directives depending on conditions in the `products` that `ng-repeat` is iterating through. Imagine, for example, that I might wish to use this directive for one type of product

```
some-product-directive datajson=product
```

and this directive for another type of product

```
some-other-product-directive datajson=product
```

How can I insert that conditional logic in a `$last` at the end of the ng-repeat

```
<div ng-repeat="product in products">   
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-1"><h2>{{ product.name }}</h2><input></input>{{product.date}}</div>

<div class="col-md-2"></div>
<div id="d{{::$id}}"></div>
</div>

<div ng="$last" some-product-directive datajson=product></div>
</div>
</div>
```

**update**
My directive uses an isolate-scope which needs access to `elem[0].previousElementSibling` in the `link` function of the directive `link: function (scope, elem, attrs)`. If I use `ng-if` for the conditional logic (as has been suggested in the answers below), which creates a child scope, then `elem[0].previousElementSibling` is `null` and the directive no longer works. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Did any of the answers below address your question?

Comment: @NewDev I haven't solved the issue yet related to the element not being available. Your answer, while informative, provides one solution at the same time it creates a new problem since ng-if creates a child scope. I don't think it's appropriate under SO rules to accept it or the other answer as the solution.

Comment: Well, this is beyond the scope of the question, imho, as there is not enough details in the question itself to help address it. Your issue is not with a child scope, but with a change in surrounding DOM structure near your directive, which suggests a problematic design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 questions here, it seems:

1. how to render something only for the last iteration of `ng-repeat`
2. how to dynamically choose which HTML to render depending on a property of `product`, and only for last iteration.

Both these questions can be addressed by using conditional rendering directives like `ng-if`, `ng-switch` and `ng-show`/`ng-hide`. The former trigger whether the HTML will be inserted in to the DOM; the latter only triggers CSS rule to show/hide.

All these directives expect an expression and evaluate its truthfulness.

And so, you could do:

```
 <div ng-repeat="product in products">
    {{product.name}}
    <div ng-if="$last">

       <div ng-if="product.type === 'some'" 
            some-product-directive datajson="product"></div>

       <div ng-if="product.type === 'some other'" 
            some-other-product-directive datajson="product"></div>

    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: This is very clear thanks. Will try it out and come back to accept later (can't test it right now)

Comment: this isn't working for me. The custom directive I'm using depends on being able to select an element from the dom `elem[0].previousElementSibling` in the `link` function of the custom directive. However, with your code, it's somehow `null` when I try to select it.

Comment: that is because `ng-if` creates a child scope. Is your directive using an isolate scope?

Comment: Yes, I believe I am. In the directive, I do `app.directive('my-directive', function () {

 return {
            restrict: 'AE', 
            scope: {
             datajson: '='
            },`

Comment: also, when I inspect the dom with my code that worked it says `div.ng-isolate-scope` and with your code it says `div.ng-scope.ng-isolate-scope`. Is there a fix?

Comment: You'd need to dive deeper into why you are accessing a previous element - was it a good idea for your directive to be so dependent on the DOM structure around it? Typically, a directive only deals with its own element tree. Perhaps there is a need for higher-level directive to organize.

Answer (score 1):

Using the wonderful `ng-if`:

```
<div ng-repeat="product in products">   
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-1"><h2>{{ product.name }}</h2><input></input>{{product.date}}</div>

<div class="col-md-2"></div>
<div id="d{{::$id}}"></div>
</div>

<div ng-if="!$last" some-other-product-directive datajson="product"></div>
<div ng-if="$last" some-product-directive datajson="product"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

You can obviously complicate the logic, and refer to a function in your controller from the `ng-if`.

Comment: I'm sorry, can you please provide a bit more information. I see `!$last` and `$last`, so how does the boolean negator `!` control the logic?  Also, I actually have three or four directives that I'm going to use, so will boolean logic even work in that situation (sorry I should have mentioned that in op)

Comment: @BrainLikeADullPencil That's why I wrote my last sentence. You can do an `ng-if="useDirectiveA()" directive-a="product"` if you have more complicated logic. The purpose of all this, is that only one div will be selected, each time, according to the logic you'll dictate.

Comment: ok, I will try it and get back to you. You were the first to post an answer, so if it's correct, I will accept it.

Comment: so are you saying that `useDirectiveA()` returns true then `directive-a="product"` will be used? and in another ng-if i run `useDirectiveB()` and if that returns true, then `directive-b="product"` will be used? like this: `<div ng-if="useDirectiveA()" some-product-directive-a datajson="product"></div><div ng-if="useDirectiveB()" some-product-directive-b datajson="product"></div>`

Comment: @BrainLikeADullPencil Yes. if `ng-if` is evaluated to false, the entire DOM element which it is on will not be rendered and will not appear. If your logic is correct, then only one `div` element will render for each iteration of the `ng-repeat` and you could use a directive for each one you want.